# Making all backgrounds clear in a UIViewControllerRepresentable instance?

Tags: swiftui, uikit

I am creating a UIViewControllerRepresentable out of a UIKit ViewController

```
func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DeleteAccountNotificationUIKitView>) -> UIViewController {
        let viewModel = NotificationModalViewModelImpl(modalType: .deleteAccount)
        let vc = NotificationModalViewController(viewModel)
        return vc
    }
```

And present it modally. However it seems that wrapping it in a UIViewControllerRepresentable adds white backgrounds to views which conflict with a half height modal displaying correctly.

As its made in a API function, i dont get scope of these parent VC's to set their background color leading to the issue in the image below:

[image]

Is there a way to solve for this? As the output SwiftUI view doesnt seem to have access to these properties either?

Answer (score 0):

In the end ive solved this myself, i had to use Introspect library to access the navigation controller that presents the SwiftUI view, and then i was able to get all the stack nav controller backgrounds to clear, as well as the hosting parent with the following code

```
        DeleteAccountNotificationUIKitView().introspectNavigationController(customize: { nav in
        nav.parent?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        nav.viewControllers.forEach { $0.view.backgroundColor = .clear }
    })
```